# Angular Component is Undefined in Jasmine Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Please help.

I think I defined test configs right.

But this throws Provider error for LayoutService.

[image: This is my test code]

[image: This is the error]

Answer (score 1):

`createSpyObj` has the following description from the
[Jasmine documentation:](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.createSpyObj)

`createSpyObj(baseName, methodNames, propertyNames)`

The method takes as arguments the name of the Service to be mocked, and the second argument is an array of all the methods inside that class that needs to be mocked.

You should pass to your spy object the original service name and methods that are used by your code.

```
spyLayoutService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CsLayoutService', ['...'])
```

Comment: I applied service name to createSpyObj but you can remain the methods array empty. I did it in other tests and that worked. but applying method name hasn't helped me.

Comment: I used same declaration but no luck.